# Convert GMT+ date to local on android

Tags: android, date, gmt

I need to convert date like Mon Nov 14 13:36:01 GMT+03:00 2016 to local. So it must be 16:36:01

```
Date serverDate; // Mon Nov 14 13:36:01 GMT+03:00 2016

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFOrmat("hh:mm:ss");
String result = dateFormat.formatDate(serverDate);
```

Result doesn't see GMT +03:00 and gives me wrong time (13:36 instead of 16:36).

Comment: What's your local time zone? If you are in GMT+3 then 13:36:01 is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is already show the GMT +3 that is 13:36 in the Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just needed to create formatter without ZZZZZ and set time zone to GMT.

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    final Date localDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2016-11-11T09:48:24-05:00");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFOrmat("hh:mm:ss");
    String result = dateFormat.formatDate(localDate); //12:48:24
```

After this code time of localDate variable will be 12:48:24 (in case of my GMT +03:00).